# Choosing Between Pushing Routes and Sub-Routes in GoRouter for Seamless Deep Linking in mobile and web apps?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

go_router version -
`go_router: ^12.1.1`

I have the following navigation use case, and I want to apply best practices using GoRouter that will work seamlessly with deep linking.

The use case involves HOME, MORE, and PROFILE SCREEN.

The PROFILE SCREEN can be navigated from both the HOME SCREEN and the MORE SCREEN. Now, I have two options: either pushing the profile route or adding as a sub-route to HOME and MORE.

What is the best option to use here, keeping in mind deep linking for PROFILE SCREEN?

I tried adding PROFILE SCREEN as a sub-route to HOME and MORE. However, if I need to add PROFILE SCREEN from any other screen, it seems impractical to keep adding it as a sub-route, which doesn't appear to be a proper way.

I also tried pushing a route, but I observed that in the web app, it does not display the URL. I'm not sure if that affects the deep linking.

I'm expecting guidance on the proper way to choose between pushing routes and using sub-routes in GoRouter for seamless deep linking in mobile and web apps.